# Why the NIntegrate can not give a result?

Tags: numerical-integration

The integrand includes ku, Sin[x], and Tuu. ku is constant, x is one of the variables, and Tuu is functions of x. I have tested that when x and y are given, Tuu can be carried out. But why NIntegrate[ku*Sin[x]*Tuu, {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}] give a result of itself (i.e.  NIntegrate[ku*Sin[x]*Tuu, {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}])? How to solve the problem? Many thanks!

According to the suggestion of Michael E2, I have rewrite the codes. But there still appear a lot of errors.

The codes are as following:

```
Clear["`*"]
m = 4;
vh = 4;
mu = 11;
delta = 8;
HBAR = SetPrecision[1.05457266*10^(-34), 50];
ME = SetPrecision[9.1093897*10^(-31), 50];
ELEC = SetPrecision[1.60217733*10^(-19), 50];
Kh = SetPrecision[0.211, 50];
vKh[1] = {0, 0, 0};
vKh[2] = {Kh, 0, 0};
kc = Sqrt[2*ME*ELEC/HBAR^2]*10^(-11);
ku = kc*Sqrt[mu + delta];
kd = kc*Sqrt[mu - delta];
a3 = {Pi/Kh, Pi/Kh, Sqrt[2]*Pi/Kh};
k[x_, y_] := {-ku*Sin[x]*Cos[y], -ku*Sin[x]*Sin[y], kz};
f11[x_, y_] := Total[(k[x, y] + vKh[1])^2] - ku^2;
f22[x_, y_] := Total[(k[x, y] + vKh[2])^2] - ku^2;
f12[x_, y_] := 
  kc^2*vh*Total[
    Table[Exp[I*n*Total[(vKh[2] - vKh[1])*a3]], {n, 0, m}]];
f21[x_, y_] := 
  kc^2*vh*Total[
    Table[Exp[I*n*Total[(vKh[1] - vKh[2])*a3]], {n, 0, m}]];
t[x_, y_] := {{f11[x, y], f12[x, y]}, {f21[x, y], f22[x, y]}};
slu[x_, y_] := 
  Select[kz /. NSolve[Det[t[x, y]] == 0, kz], 
   Re[#] >= 0 && Im[#] >= 0 &];
td1[x_, y_] := t[x, y] /. kz -> slu[x, y][[1]];
td2[x_, y_] := t[x, y] /. kz -> slu[x, y][[2]]
nu1[x_, y_] := Flatten[NullSpace[td1[x, y]]];
nu2[x_, y_] := Flatten[NullSpace[td2[x, y]]];
pi[x_, y_] := Transpose[{nu1[x, y], nu2[x, y]}];
pei := Table[If[q == 1, 1, 0], {q, 2}];
Tuu[x_, y_] := 
  Im[Conjugate[(LinearSolve[pi[x, y], pei][[1]]*nu1[x, y][[1]]*
          Exp[I*slu[x, y][[1]]*d] + 
         LinearSolve[pi[x, y], pei][[2]]*nu2[x, y][[1]]*
          Exp[I*slu[x, y][[2]]*d])]*(Dt[
        LinearSolve[pi[x, y], pei][[1]]*nu1[x, y][[1]]*
          Exp[I*slu[x, y][[1]]*d] + 
         LinearSolve[pi[x, y], pei][[2]]*nu2[x, y][[1]]*
          Exp[I*slu[x, y][[2]]*d], d]) + 
     Conjugate[(LinearSolve[pi[x, y], pei][[1]]*nu1[x, y][[2]]*
          Exp[I*slu[x, y][[1]]*d] + 
         LinearSolve[pi[x, y], pei][[2]]*nu2[x, y][[2]]*
          Exp[I*slu[x, y][[2]]*d])]*(Dt[
        LinearSolve[pi[x, y], pei][[1]]*nu1[x, y][[2]]*
          Exp[I*slu[x, y][[1]]*d] + 
         LinearSolve[pi[x, y], pei][[2]]*nu2[x, y][[2]]*
          Exp[I*slu[x, y][[2]]*d], d]) /. d -> 2*10^(-9)];
Guu := NIntegrate[ku*Sin[x]*Tuu[x, y], {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}];
Guu
```

Comment: Does it give an error? Does it take longer than you're willing to wait?  Does it run out of memory?  Does it cause a crash?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your reminder. I have re-edited the question.

Comment: @Bill If you give the values of x and y, you can find Tuu can be carried out.

Comment: @Bill But I have the answer of 1.551584515978786723934004674758063793199421595*10^10.

Comment: @Bill I guess you should change yy to y.

Comment: @Bill It doesn't matter.

Comment: You have constants that differ by dozens of orders of magnitude; numerical results will be catastrophically bad. Please, work in natural units, where all parameters are of order one.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I have change the parameters to order one, but it does not work.

Comment: @user59546 Update the code then.

Comment: Your re-edit is not really accurate: I get loads of error messages and you report none, even though my first question was whether you got errors. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/IcJWL.png  --  I would say that probably the issues lie with poor programming practice.  It's better to write functions in which all the dependencies appear in their arguments.  For instance, `LinearSolve` should probably not be evaluated until the matrix-vector arguments are completely numeric.  But you cannot control that with the way your code is written.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much! I'm sorry that the errors have not been added.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have write functions in which all the dependencies appear in their arguments. But there still appear a lot of errors. What I should do next?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I have rewritten the functions in which all the dependencies appear in their arguments, and the above codes have been renewed. But there still appear a lot of errors. What I should do next?

Comment: I think you missed my glancing remark about `NumericQ`:  Try `Tuu[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := ...` -- You may want to add it to any other function that might get called at the "top level" (like `Tuu` gets called by `NIntegrate`) and which requires `x` and `y` to be numbers for them to work without errors.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much! However, it will also takes a long time. Besides rewrite the Tuu, is there any other methods to optimize the codes?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Besides the long time, the error "NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small." will also appear.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few programming issues:

1. It's better to write functions in which all the dependencies appear in their arguments.  This requires a complete rewrite which I'm not going to do.
2. You need to control the evaluation of certain parts of the code
3. You compute the solution the same linear problem in the code for `Tuu` eight times.  It's not incorrect, but it wastes time.
4. The condition `Im[#] >= 0` in the code for `slu` does not accommodate rounding error on zero imaginary part, if the error were a small negative number.
5. Non-issue: Some will complain about the scale of the parameters (i.e. numbers of the order `10^-31`).  Often problems with numerics are due to the size of numbers getting out of hand and catastrophic round-off error.  But not always.  This has yet to prove to be an issue in this particular set of problems (see OP's other recent posts), and the scale of the numbers in the computations have fit comfortably within the range of double-precision floats.

First of all, there are all these errors that were not mentioned in the question:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

They arise because `NSolve` and probably `LinearSolve` should not be evaluated until the expressions involved are completely numeric (see advice on [`_?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)).  But that cannot be controlled with the way the code is written (see point 1 above).
It can be see that the same errors come from evaluating `Tuu` when `x` and `y` do not have numeric values.  If we give them numeric values first, then `Tuu` evaluates to a number without errors.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first error you get from `NIntegrate[]` originates in `td[1]`.  This is easy to figure out in V11, because you can click on the three-dot button next to the error message and select "Show Stack Trace".
It comes up formatted a little more nicely than shown below.  We see in lines 2-4 some of the code for `td[1]` and in line five we see the function call.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Below is one way to get `NIntegrate` to compute something, but given all the programming issues, I cannot guarantee the value is correct:

```
(* takes a long time -- didn't time it (maybe 10-20 minutes?) *)
myG[xx_?NumericQ, yy_?NumericQ] := Block[{x = xx, y = yy},
   ku*Sin[x]*Tuu
   ];
NIntegrate[myG[x, y], {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/4}]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

```
(*  1.8222*10^20  *)
```